# Rails 4 - updating multiple table entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have around 25 items left for a product represented as `product.stock = 25`. Say I sell 5 of this specific product. Then I need to update the remaining stock entry for it to `25 - 5 = 20` or `product.stock = product.stock - purchase.quantity`.

How would I do this in my app. Would I place the above code somewhere in my controller?

I have a purchasing form that caters to the following:

- able to select existing product, retrieves the price for the product
- specify the quantity amount the user would like to purchase
- display the total and the total of all the products selected for purchase

I am not sure if I am being clear here or if the subject is relevant to my question.

Comment: Just to clear things up: You have a view in which someone attempts to sell 5 items, correct? They fill in a box of some sort with "5", and then hit submit?

Comment: Yes @Micah that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use ActiveRecord's [decrement!](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/decrement!) method:

```
product.decrement!(:stock, purchase.quantity)
```

If the Purchase model is what tracks the final sale, then I would put this code in an ActiveRecord callback.  For example:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  after_create :adjust_inventory

  def adjust_inventory
    product.decrement!(:stock, quantity)
  end
end
```

Purchase should also have a `before_save` validation that ensures enough stock exists to satisfy the order.

Comment: I plan to create a back order entry and have that update as well for if we are low on stock for a specific order. Thank you, this worked for the purpose of the question, I'll now try to figure out the `:back_order` and `before_save`.

Comment: I have posted a continuation to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24565599/rails-4-updating-multiple-table-entries-products-and-backorder

Answer (score 0):

The method to decrement your stock should be implemented in the Product model

`def decrement_stock(qty)
  self.stock = self.stock - qty
  self.save
 end`

In your controller, you should call this method based on your params.

purchase_controller.rb

`def update
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  # Add validation to make sure you have any stock
  @product.decrement_stock(params[:quantity])
  # Add other things you need to do and return the @product
end`

This is a fairly simplified version. You should actually have an Order model, an OrderLine model and a Product.

Comment: and where would I call the function?

Comment: I udpdated the answer

Comment: I would argue that perhaps either the save should be done in the controller... or that the decrement_stock method should use an exclamation point... or possibly both

Comment: @Rafal I actually do have an order model, as well as a product model and purchases acting as the orderline

Comment: As @user3334690 i would avoid saving in the models whenever possible or make it apparent that you are in order to avoid redundant calls that could cause issues with `before/after_save` functions

Comment: @Micah that's what I'm saying

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at https://github.com/spree/spree
Its an ecommerce gem for Rails. Im sure you can inspire yourself from it and implement a simpler solution if you require something smaller