# Rails 4 - updating multiple table entries - products and backorder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

When the user purchases a product, I need to adjust the inventory of the product (`product.stock`). If the user wants a larger quantity than what is available, then I would like to store in `product.backorder` how much I have to order.

The code in the following model is the algorithm I came up with that makes sense to me, but I receive the following error in my controller when I add `:backorder = :backorder + amount.abs` and `:stock = 0`. Those variables are part of the product table, perhaps I can not write to them from the purchase model?

`syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end`

#### #app/controllers/orders_controller.rb

```
def show
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  @purchases = @order.purchases #this line is highlighted
end
```

#### #Purchase Model

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
    #... other code
    belongs_to :product

 after_create :adjust_inventory

 def adjust_inventory
    amount = :stock - quantity

    unless amount < 0
        product.decrement!(:stock, quantity)
    else
        backordered = amount.abs
        :backorder = :backorder + amount.abs
        :stock = 0
        product.save
        purchase.save
    end
 end
end
```

#### #products table

```
...
t.string   "name"
t.decimal  "price"
t.integer  "stock"
t.integer  "backorder"
```

#### #purchases table

```
...
t.string   "name"
t.integer  "quantity" # amount client would like to purchase
t.decimal  "price"
t.integer  "backordered" # amount to restock and give to the client
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I'm pretty sure it updates the product and purchase 
records the way you intended.

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  after_create :adjust_inventory

  def adjust_inventory
    amount = product.stock - quantity

    unless amount < 0
      product.decrement!(:stock, quantity)
    else      
      product.update(
        backorder:  (product.backorder || 0) + amount.abs,
        stock: 0
      )

      self.backordered = amount.abs
      save
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: not sure why but I get `NoMethodError - undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: try this: backorder:  (product.backorder||0) + (amount.abs||0)

Comment: @AhmadHussain That worked, great!! Thanks. What does `||0` do?

Comment: @kadhim, it means `or zero`. In other words, if backorder is nil use 0 instead (0 + amount.abs).

Comment: it will check if backorder is nil then use 0